# Opening my connection in C# to SQL

Tags: c#, sql

I have a problem connecting to a database in C#. I can get and verify my connection string was retrieved, but after trying to open the connection, it fails to open. No error messages, simply returns false on it being open.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

SqlConnection dConnection = new SqlConnection();
public bool isCurrentOpen;

public string ErrorMsg = "";
public int attempt;
public int MaxRetry = 5;

public bool OpenDBConnection(string ConnectionString)
{
    attempt = 0;          
    if(ConnectionString == null)
        ConnectionString = cConn.SetConnectionString();             

        isCurrentOpen = (dConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open);   

        while (!isCurrentOpen && attempt < MaxRetry)                   
        {
            try
            {
                dConnection.Open();                                 
                attempt++;                                          

                if (isCurrentOpen)                                  
                    break;                                         

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorMsg += ex.Message;                            
                attempt++;                                         
            }
        }
        return isCurrentOpen;                                      
    }
}
```

What do you think?

Here is where the connection string is retrieved

```
public string ConnectionString = "";

            public string GetConnectionString(string ConnectionString)
    {

        if(ConnectionString == "")
        {
             ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[1].ConnectionString.ToString();
            // Retrieves the Application Settings File and retrieves the Connection String
        }

        return ConnectionString;
    }

     public string SetConnectionString()
     {
         try
        {
            ConnectionString = this.GetConnectionString(ConnectionString);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorMsg += ex.Message;
        }

        return ConnectionString;
    }
```

changed to different database and used a SQLCompact database and got the same result and returned the connection string in the file again 
I don't have enough reputation points to screenshot the results to you

Comment: What are using your connection for?

Comment: Im building a library that I can use in multiple applications to get the connection string, open/close the connection and handle data transactions. My goal is to not have to hard code in every single time. when I can simply, in generic form work with any database that my applications will use.

Comment: Now, I am certain. Your connection string is not set in your connection.

Comment: ill Rerun and see. can you screenshot on here? I'm new

Comment: @Dolarzo - I decided to return the error message as well, to see as to why it failed to open. it is not being initialized. Any suggestions, other than hard code it directly into the connection module?

Comment: @Dalorzo I will try this when I get to my other computer where the file is located. I will send feedback tomorrow. thank you for your assistance in the mean time.

Comment: @Dalorzo Crap! sorry, again, I am new, I got lost in the sauce here for a few.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find in your code when the connection string is assigned to your database connection object. Can you try assign it on your open connection method?

To answer your second question, how to resolve this in your current library. this what I would suggest you to do:

```
public bool OpenDBConnection(string ConnectionString)
{
    attempt = 0;          
    if(ConnectionString == null)
        ConnectionString = cConn.SetConnectionString();             
    isCurrentOpen = (dConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open);   

    if (!isCurrentOpen) //to keep up with your logic in case a connection is already opened.
         dConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString); //Initialize Database connection with the Connection String    
     ...
```

Comment: it is in another module. where the if statement asked if the ConnectionString == "" it called the other module. I can add the code for that, that part is not the issue though I do not believe. the code, when tested, retrieves the exact connection string from the Configuration file for the application.

Comment: I don't think it is happening. Can you try it on this method to confirm or discard?

Comment: I applied it to a textbox display on a form and returned the string to the textbox to test it... I originally thought the same thing. I posted more code above to show the other module so you can see

Answer (score 2):

You don't update the value of your boolean after the attempt to open the connection

```
isCurrentOpen = (dConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open);   
while (!isCurrentOpen && attempt < MaxRetry)                   
{
    try
    {
        dConnection.Open();                                 
        attempt++;                                          

        // You need to re-evaluate this boolean
        isCurrentOpen = (dConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open);   

        // And, there is no need to break out here, because the loop will terminate 
        // itself if the isCurrentOpen == true
        // if (isCurrentOpen)                                  
        //      break;                                         
    }
    ....
}
return isCurrentOpen;
```

**EDIT** Looking at your edit it seems that you don't pass the ConnectionString to the connection object. Without it the connection has no clue how to open your database

```
public bool OpenDBConnection(string ConnectionString)
{
    attempt = 0;          
    isCurrentOpen = (dConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open);   
    if(isCurrentOpen == false)
    {
       // If no connectionstring received, get it from the config
       if(ConnectionString == null)
           ConnectionString = cConn.GetConnectionString();    

       // Assign the connectionstring to the connection to be opened
       dConnection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
       while (!isCurrentOpen && attempt < MaxRetry)                   
       {
           try
           {
               dConnection.Open();   
               ......
```

Comment: It fails to open the connection or still returns false after opening the connection? Also, in your try/catch you record the error but you don't show it anywhere. Do you have an error opening that connection? If yes, just for debug, try to display it with a messagebox or a Debug.WriteLine.

Comment: But what is the error message? If something is wrong with the connection string you should output the error messages catched by the catch block.

Comment: @steve I recorded the error in another form as I called it when testing. it isn't initializing the string before attempting to open the connection. I am going to do some more work around and try to remedy this.

Answer (score 0):

you can do similar like this...

Store Connection String in App.Config File and make Global Class for Your project

Here is a Sample Code of App.Config File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

 <configuration>
 <appSettings>
<add key="ConnString" value="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=yourdatabase;Integrated Security=True" />
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Global Class Code is

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;

namespace DAL

{

 public class GlobalClass

{
    public string connectionString;

    public GlobalClass() 
    {
        connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ConnString");
    }
}}
```

and You Can Inherit Global class to Your Remaining Project Class I hope this this will help you

Here We Consider Employe Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

 namespace Employe
 {
   public class Employe : GlobalClass
{
    public Employe()
    {
    }
 //Sample Method 
     public DataTable FillRoleComboBox()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select * from TBLEMPLOYEE", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
        SDA.SelectCommand = comm;
        SDA.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
}
}
```